# Data annotation is working on editing only

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

```
Here is my controller codes

//
        // GET: /Department/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View(new department());
        } 

        //
        // POST: /Department/Create

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(department dept)
        {
            try
            {
                dbContext.AddTodepartments(dept);
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        //
        // GET: /Department/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            return View(dbContext.departments.Single(d => d.DeptID == id));
        }

        //
        // POST: /Department/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
        {
            var dept = dbContext.departments.Single(d => d.DeptID == id);
            try
            {
                UpdateModel(dept);
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View(dept);
            }
        }

Here is the partial class 

    [MetadataType(typeof(DepartmentMetaData))]
    public partial class department
    {
    }
    public class DepartmentMetaData
    {
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Department name required.")]
        public string DeptName { get; set; }
    }


    The required field validation is happening on the editing only. I can insert a null 'Department name' but on eding the values, it is not allowing to enter a null value.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Should do [ModelState.IsValid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstatedictionary.isvalid.aspx) check when creating record. More on ModelState [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881281/what-is-modelstate-isvalid-valid-for-in-asp-net-mvc-in-nerddinner/881351#881351)