# What does ModelState.IsValid do?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, modelstate

When I do a create method i bind my object in the parameter and then I check if `ModelState` is valid so I add to the database:

But when I need to change something before I add to the database (before I change it the `ModelState` couldn't be valid so I have to do it)
why the model state still non valid.

What does this function check exactly?

This is my example:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "EncaissementID,libelle,DateEncaissement,Montant,ProjetID,Description")] Encaissement encaissement) {
  encaissement.Montant = Convert.ToDecimal(encaissement.Montant);
  ViewBag.montant = encaissement.Montant;
  if (ModelState.IsValid) {
    db.Encaissements.Add(encaissement);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Encaissement");
  };
  ViewBag.ProjetID = new SelectList(db.Projets, "ProjetId", "nomP");
  return View(encaissement);
}
```

Comment: Do you have any required attributes on your model?  If any of those required fields are not entered, the models state will not be valid.

Comment: all the required attributes are entered but my model state still non valid !

Comment: Look at my answer, perhaps your view is binding to int or datetime that is not nullable, and this can also cause ModelState to be invalid.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`ModelState.IsValid` indicates if it was possible to bind the incoming values from the request to the model correctly and whether any explicitly specified validation rules were broken during the model binding process.

In your example, the model that is being bound is of class type `Encaissement`.  Validation rules are those specified on the model by the use of attributes, logic and errors added within the `IValidatableObject`'s `Validate()` method - or simply within the code of the action method.

The `IsValid` property will be true if the values were able to bind correctly to the model AND no validation rules were broken in the process.

Here's an example of how a validation attribute and `IValidatableObject` might be implemented on your model class:

```
public class Encaissement : IValidatableObject
{
    // A required attribute, validates that this value was submitted    
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Encaissment ID must be submitted")]
    public int EncaissementID { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DateEncaissement { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

        // Validate the DateEncaissment
        if (!this.DateEncaissement.HasValue)
        {
            results.Add(new ValidationResult("The DateEncaissement must be set", new string[] { "DateEncaissement" });
        }

       return results;
    }
}
```

Here's an example of how the same validation rule may be applied within the action method of your example:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "EncaissementID,libelle,DateEncaissement,Montant,ProjetID,Description")] Encaissement encaissement) {

  // Perform validation
  if (!encaissement.DateEncaissement.HasValue)
  {
      this.ModelState.AddModelError("DateEncaissement", "The DateEncaissement must be set");
  }

  encaissement.Montant = Convert.ToDecimal(encaissement.Montant);

  ViewBag.montant = encaissement.Montant;

  if (ModelState.IsValid) {

    db.Encaissements.Add(encaissement);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Encaissement");

  };

  ViewBag.ProjetID = new SelectList(db.Projets, "ProjetId", "nomP");

  return View(encaissement);
}
```

It's worth bearing in mind that the value types of the properties of your model will also be validated.  For example, you can't assign a string value to an `int` property.  If you do, it won't be bound and the error will be added to your `ModelState` too.

In your example, the `EncaissementID` value could not have a value of `"Hello"` posted to it, this would cause a model validation error to be added and `IsValid` will be false.

It is for any of the above reasons (and possibly more) that the `IsValid` bool value of the model state will be `false`.

Comment: thank's but it still fuggy ! when i change somethig in my model for exemple i need to convert a string to a decimal then i  add to the database .. the modelstate.isvalid checks the model passed in the parameter not the state after my updates ?

Comment: Luke, could you explain why there is no need anymore to call `ModelState.IsValid` in ASP.NET Core 3.0? It seems model validation happens automatically, even in some old projects like ASP.NET Core 2.2 and the likes.

Thank you!

Answer (score 27):

`ModelState.IsValid` will basically tell you if there is any issues with your data posted to the server, based on the data annotations added to the properties of your model.

If, for instance, you have a `[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please fill")]`, and that property is empty when you post your form to the server, ModelState will be invalid.

The ModelBinder also checks some basic stuff for you. If, for instance, you have a BirthDate datepicker, and the property that this picker is binding to, is not a nullable `DateTime` type, your ModelState will also be invalid if you have left the date empty.

[Here](http://www.exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-mvc-demystified-modelstate/), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881281/what-is-modelstate-isvalid-valid-for-in-asp-net-mvc-in-nerddinner) are some useful posts to read.

Answer (score 4):

You can find a great write-up on ModelState and its uses [here](http://www.exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-mvc-demystified-modelstate/).

Specifically, the `IsValid` property is a quick way to check if there are any field validation errors in `ModelState.Errors`. If you're not sure what's causing your Model to be invalid by the time it POST's to your controller method, you can inspect the `ModelState["Property"].Errors` property, which should yield at least one form validation error.

Edit: Updated with proper dictionary syntax from @ChrisPratt

Comment: ModelState.Errors doesn't exist ! there is : SerializeErrors , and AddModelError that's all

Comment: It's `ModelState["Property"].Errors`. In other words, `ModelState` is a kind of dictionary. Any property on your model that is posted will get a key. You have to index the dictionary on the appropriate property, to see the errors for that property. If you're just trying to figure out what's erroring out, debug and put a breakpoint somewhere in your post action. Then, inspect `ModelState`, key by key, looking at the `Errors` collection on each one.

Answer (score 0):

This is not meant to be the best answer, but I find my errors by stepping through the **ModelState Values** to find the one with the error in Visual Studio's debugger:

[image: screenshot]

My guess is that everyone with a question about why their ModelState is not valid could benefit from placing a breakpoint in the code, inspecting the values, and finding the one (or more) that is invalid.

This is not the best way to run a production website, but this is how a developer finds out what is wrong with the code.