# ASP.NET MVC C# DataTypeAttribute on parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes, modelstate

I have tried using `EmailAddressAttribute` on a parameter posted to a controller but it doesn't have the same effect as if it was used within a model.

This is my code:

```
    public void AddEmail(int id, [EmailAddress]string emailAddress)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            throw new Exception();
    }
```

The `emailAddress` parameter is within the `ModelState` but it's always valid. However, if I use it within a model like below then it works perfectly fine.

```
    public class TestModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [EmailAddress]
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    }

    public void AddEmail(TestModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            throw new Exception();
    }
```

The `EmailAddressAttribute` class has the `AttributeTargets.Parameter` so I thought it would work the same.

Can anyone confirm if this is just the way it is? Or is there a way to get it to work the same as the model does?

EDIT: I am using .NET Framework 4.6.2.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can use `DataTypeAttributes` as parameters in a function. 
But as an easy way to just check if it is a valid email notation you could use this code:

```
try {
    var addr = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(email);
    return addr.Address == email;
}
catch {
    return false;
}
```

---

**EDIT 1:**

As mentioned from Mark Vincze [here](https://blog.markvincze.com/how-to-validate-action-parameters-with-dataannotation-attributes/) on his blog, you could create a new `ActionFilterAttribute` like this when you want to have attributes in your action parameters.

```
public class ValidateActionParametersAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var descriptor = context.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;

        if (descriptor != null)
        {
            var parameters = descriptor.MethodInfo.GetParameters();

            foreach (var parameter in parameters)
            {
                var argument = context.ActionArguments[parameter.Name];

                EvaluateValidationAttributes(parameter, argument, context.ModelState);
            }
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }

    private void EvaluateValidationAttributes(ParameterInfo parameter, object argument, ModelStateDictionary modelState)
    {
        var validationAttributes = parameter.CustomAttributes;

        foreach (var attributeData in validationAttributes)
        {
            var attributeInstance = CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttribute(parameter, attributeData.AttributeType);

            var validationAttribute = attributeInstance as ValidationAttribute;

            if (validationAttribute != null)
            {
                var isValid = validationAttribute.IsValid(argument);
                if (!isValid)
                {
                    modelState.AddModelError(parameter.Name, validationAttribute.FormatErrorMessage(parameter.Name));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this also just workes for `Actions`. Because the `ModelState`-Class was created to make it easier to check if an **incoming binding** is valid or not and not just to validate random objects. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36894368/5398388) is more about that.

So in your case when `AddEmail` is a 'normal' method and not an `Action` you should not use this. In this case, use another validation method such as my first answer.

And if you want to read even more about validation, take a look at [this](https://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/01/input-validation-vs-model-validation-in-aspnet-mvc.html) blog post from Brad Wilson.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If this was the case then why would it allow you to use these attributes on parameters?

Comment: @Murphybro2 added some more information about that topic. maybe this helps you more.