# Asp.net MVC model validating

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, model

I`m new On Asp.net Mvc (4)

can I call a function to validate a model property ( It is more than REQUIRED , MAXLENGHT...)

e.g:

```
public class Movie 

{

   public int ID { get; set; }

   [Required]
   public string Title { get; set; }

   [DataType(DataType.Date)]
   public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

   [Required]
   public string Genre { get; set; }

   [Range(1, 100)]
   [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
   public decimal Price { get; set; }

   [StringLength(5)]
   public string Rating { get; set; }
   [***Call some function here***]

   public string blabla{get;set;}
}
```

Or maybe another idea?

Comment: what's your question? you can use `ModelState.IsValid` in your controller. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/881351/1849444) is good explanation.

Comment: @Nima Ghaferi, You can use remote validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by imlementing a custom validation attribute [check this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668224%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)

Example:

```
public sealed class DateEndAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public string DateStart { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        // Get value of datestart property
        string dateStartString = HttpContext.Current.Request[DateStart];
        DateTime dateEnd = (DateTime)value;
        DateTime dateStart = DateTime.Parse(dateStartString);

        // Start must be before end
        return dateStart <= dateEnd;
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return name + " has to be after startdate";
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "StartDate")]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "EndDate")]
    [DateEnd(DateStart = "StartDate")]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
```