# How to avoid to pass null entity object to web api method

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have below web api method as below

```
public bool UpdateValidations([FromBody] ValidationKeyEntity validationKey)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    { 
        //my code here
    }
}

public class ValidationKeyEntity
{
    public int ValidationKeyId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(Constants.maxStringLength)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int DisplayId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(Constants.maxStringLength)]
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

I am doing testing using Postman .I am passing  different json than ValidationKeyEntity object as { "Vishal": "vishal" }  as parameter .
But still my  **ModelState.IsValid returns true**.

**How can I avoid accepting other json object than "ValidationKeyEntity" object?**

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881281/what-is-modelstate-isvalid-valid-for-in-asp-net-mvc-in-nerddinner

Comment: I suggest you create your own ModelBinder and use it in place of [FromBody] in your method.  You are more than likely going to perform validation anyway and you work with the framework pipeline so you know when you get into your method that you have a "valid" object, whatever "valid" means to you.  IMO ModelBinders are an underused aspect of ASP.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [RequiredAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DDE-DE%26k%3Dk(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2) to mark the properties as `required`:

   ```
   public class ValidationKeyEntity
   {
       [Required]
       public int ValidationKeyId { get; set; }

       [Required]
       public string Name { get; set; }

       [Required]
       public int DisplayId { get; set; }

       [Required]
       public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Set [MissingMemberHandling](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeMissingMemberHandling.htm) globally to handle waste properties:

   ```
   var httpConfiguration = new HttpConfiguration();

   httpConfiguration
                   .Formatters
                   .JsonFormatter
                   .SerializerSettings
                   .MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error;
   ```